# KeyBoard with Textfield animated together into view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to have a textfield above the NumberPad so that when showKeyboard is tapped, both the UIView (with textfield and "add" button) + NumberPad is animated into view together.  I am able to get them into view separately, but not at the same time..  I am not sure what happens.  If I press showKeyboard once, the numberPad appears, if I press again the UIView (with textfield and "add" button) animates into view.  How can I get both the numberPad and UIView to transition into view together ?
Any help would be very much appreciated !

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var showKeyboard: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var addData: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapshowKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {

        inputField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        inputField.becomeFirstResponder()

        let height = containerView.frame.size.height
        let width = containerView.frame.size.width

        //New X Position (same)
        let xPosition = containerView.frame.origin.x // i.e. 0

        //New Y position
        let yPosition = containerView.frame.origin.y - 270

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: width , height: height) })

        println("tapped")
    }
}
```

[image: NUmberPad with textfield]

Comment: Try this `inputField .inputAccessoryView=self.containerView;` this is objective-c code.

Comment: Afraid that did not make a difference.  Still have to tap twice to get both keyboard and UIView into view.

Comment: add toolBar above keyboard with two barButtonItems as textfield and button instead of using your animation.

Comment: I have a solution for you in objective c, if it's helpful? And by the way, it's not considered good practice to set the UITextField in hard coded values since you have several devices with different view sizes.

Comment: Sure, it gives me a startingpoint!

Answer (score 1):

You should do all the animation calculations in the keyboardWillShow notifier: (substitute _textField the view that holds all the elements you want to display. Note that this method will fire once your textfield becomes first responder).

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //this is the time interval for the animation time
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    NSInteger animationCurve = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    //Get the keyboard frame to calculate your UITextField position
    CGRect keybFrame = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue];

   //set the textField frame to bottom of screen, before animating it up with the keyboard
   _textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, kTextFieldHeight);

   //setting a new frame to the textField
   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - keybFrame.size.height) - kTextFieldHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, kTextFieldHeight);

   [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:animationCurve animations:^{
        //Making it visible
       _textField.alpha = 1.0;
       _textField.frame = frame;
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

Comment: Ahh, ok yeah I understand.  The logic seems correct, I will need o translate it before I accept it though.  Thanks !